# Auth for squid in combination IP, Username and password

Tags: passwords, ip, combinations, squid

I run a squid Proxy with ncsa_auth and want to restrict clients to use the same credentials from different networks (they have public static IPs). As squid logs which username from which public IP logged in, it must be possible. I want to make a list of usernames matching to the IP addresses. So credentials are valid only from that particular IP address. How might I do that?

Answer (score 4):

acl mahmoud src 10.0.0.63

auth_param basic program /usr/lib/squid/ncsa_auth /etc/squid/passwd

auth_param basic children 5

auth_param basic realm Squid proxy-caching web server

auth_param basic credentialsttl 2 hours

auth_param basic casesensitive off

acl ncsa_users proxy_auth REQUIRED

http_access allow ncsa_users mahmoud all